# How in Django can I specify in my view code whether a field is mandatory or not?

Tags: django, validation, django-views

I have a field in a model (and a form) that won't always be mandatory, but will be from certain screens.

I'm currently using `modelform_factory` to quickly convert the model to a form; can I specify when it should be mandatory using this method, or if not, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about a form? You are using ModelForm with this particular model? If so, you can just do this like that:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):

    your_model_field = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

If you're not talking about forms, please be more specific and include code.

**EDIT:**

Can you put the code you use in your question? Otherwise let me know why `modelform_factory` would be better in your situation than using `ModelForm`. The `modelform_factory` function returns a `ModelForm` class, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/

Also, I'm not sure you can do what you want with just `modelform_factory` as this is used for simple `ModelForm` without much customizations. More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense, thanks. I'm using `modelform_factory` - let me update the question.

Comment: I think you've already answered the question :) You're saying I unfortunately need to make the jump from using the very concise `modelform_factory` syntax to creating a new class. Was just hoping it wouldn't have to get as verbose as that.

Comment: Sorry, I know you've answered the question, but the field is a foreign key to a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object. How do I specify that in a `ModelForm`?

Comment: You should use [`forms.ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and pass a queryset.

Comment: There's another way to do it: make the field mandatory on the `Model` and just pick whether or not to use the field in `modelform_factory`. When the result is POSTed back, do `form.save(commit=False)` on it and if I didn't show the field on the screen, then add its value programmatically. I like this (at the moment) because I can specify it all without creating a separate `ModelForm`.

Comment: Thanks for your help though; I doubt I can stretch `modelform_factory` much further and will have to switch to full `ModelForm`s.